# select the element which match the start-with name

Tags: xslt

I have a XML like this

```
<extra>
    <name>format-xml</name>
    <value>excel.xls</value>
</extra>
<extra>
    <name>format-java</name>
    <value>hello.java</value>
</extra>
<extra>
    <name>Date</name>
    <value>someday</value>
</extra>
<extra>
    <name>version</name>
    <value>2</value>
</extra>
```

I would like to use XSLT to get he foamt-* name

I try the start-with, but it doesn't work

```
<xsl:for-each select="extra[starts-with(name(),'format-')]">
    Format name:  <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
    Format value:  <xsl:apply-templates select="value" />           
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`name()` will give you the name of the context node (which in your example is `<extra>`).  You are trying to match on the `<name>` element's value.

**Adjust your select statement to:**

```
extra[starts-with(name,'format-')]
```